using 21.1.1 keycloak kemanager with 2.1.0 wso2 apim
I am trying to integrate WSO2 API Manager (version 2.1.0) with Keycloak (version 21.1.1) as the key manager. I followed the configuration steps outlined in the documentation at this link (https://github.com/sajithab/apim-keymanager-keycloak/blob/master/docs/config.md). However, after updating the <API-M_HOME>/repository/conf/api-manager.xml file with the following configuration:
    <APIKeyManager>
        <KeyManagerClientImpl>org.wso2.keycloak.client.KeycloakClient</KeyManagerClientImpl>
        <Configuration>
            <ServerURL>http://localhost:9001</ServerURL>
            <keycloakInstanceUrl>http://localhost:9001</keycloakInstanceUrl>
            <keycloakRealmName>apim</keycloakRealmName>
                <client_id>apim-client</client_id>
                <Username>apim-user</Username>
                <Password>apim-password</Password>
            <username>apim-user</username>
                <password>apim-password</password>
            <consumerKey>apim-client</consumerKey>
                <consumerSecret>HTCSxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxCeb6O</consumerSecret>
            <ConsumerKey>apim-client</ConsumerKey>
                <ConsumerSecret>HTCSxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxCeb6O</ConsumerSecret>
            <TokenURL>http://localhost:9001/realms/apim/protocol/openid-connect/token</TokenURL>
            <RevokeURL>http://localhost:9001/realms/apim/protocol/openid-connect/revoke</RevokeURL>
        </Configuration>
    </APIKeyManager>

the WSO2 Store stops displaying the application list. Instead, I encounter the following error in the UI:

Even after I add an application, it appears in the wso2 database, but I can't add it again due to a 'Duplicate application' error. However, it doesn't show up on this screen.
And in the wso2carbon.log, I see the following error messages:
TID: [-1234] [] [2024-10-08 14:03:02,628] ERROR {JAGGERY.site.blocks.application.application-list.ajax.application-list:jag} -  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 {JAGGERY.site.blocks.application.application-list.ajax.application-list:jag}
TID: [-1234] [] [2024-10-08 14:03:02,686] ERROR {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager} -  org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from null (/store/site/blocks/application/application-list/ajax/application-list.jag#114) {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager}
org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from null (/store/site/blocks/application/application-list/ajax/application-list.jag#114)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:571)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:588)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:508)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doGet(JaggeryServlet.java:24)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:747)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:377)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1756)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1715)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from null (/store/site/blocks/application/application-list/ajax/application-list.jag#114)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3687)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3665)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3693)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3712)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.undefReadError(ScriptRuntime.java:3725)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1483)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.application.application_list.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/store/site/blocks/application/application-list/ajax/application-list.jag:114)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.application.application_list.ajax.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/application/application-list/ajax/application-list.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.application.application_list.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/store/site/blocks/application/application-list/ajax/application-list.jag:4)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.application.application_list.ajax.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/application/application-list/ajax/application-list.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.application.application_list.ajax.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/application/application-list/ajax/application-list.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.application.application_list.ajax.c0.exec(/store/site/blocks/application/application-list/ajax/application-list.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
        ... 45 more
TID: [-1] [] [2024-10-08 14:03:05,876]  WARN {java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences} -  Could not lock System prefs. Unix error code 32745. {java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences}
TID: [-1] [] [2024-10-08 14:03:05,877]  WARN {java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences} -  Couldn't flush system prefs: java.util.prefs.BackingStoreException: Couldn't get file lock. {java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences}
^[[B^[[B^[[BTID: [-1234] [] [2024-10-08 14:03:26,970] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.throttle.service.interceptors.auth.BasicAuthenticationInterceptor} -  Authenticating request: null {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.throttle.service.interceptors.auth.BasicAuthenticationInterceptor}
TID: [-1234] [] [2024-10-08 14:03:26,970] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.throttle.service.interceptors.auth.BasicAuthenticationInterceptor} -  Authenticating request: null {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.throttle.service.interceptors.auth.BasicAuthenticationInterceptor}
TID: [-1234] [] [2024-10-08 14:03:26,995] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.throttle.service.interceptors.auth.BasicAuthenticationInterceptor} -  User logged into Web app using Basic Authentication {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.throttle.service.interceptors.auth.BasicAuthenticationInterceptor}
TID: [-1234] [] [2024-10-08 14:03:26,995] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.throttle.service.interceptors.auth.BasicAuthenticationInterceptor} -  User logged into Web app using Basic Authentication {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.throttle.service.interceptors.auth.BasicAuthenticationInterceptor}  

Could anyone please assist me in troubleshooting this issue?
